# C++ Excepción de coma flotante

Tags: c++

Estoy comenzando con la programación en C++ y me surgió la siguiente duda. Tengo este código:

```
// Determina multiplos

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 0;

    cout << "Ingrese dos numeros: ";
    cin >> num1 >> num2;
    if (num1 % num2 == 0) cout << num1 << " es multiplo de " << num2 << endl;
    if (num1 % num2 != 0) cout << num1 << " no es multiplo de " << num2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Estoy probando ingresando valores erróneos. Por ejemplo, si a ambas variables les paso números decimales, o únicamente a la primera, VS Code me tira "Excepción de coma flotante ('core generado').
Sin embargo, si el primer número es un entero, y el segundo decimal, me trunca el segundo y funciona lo más bien.

A qué se debe esta diferencia?

Muchas gracias. Saludos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esto te pasa porque estás haciendo fallar la extracción de enteros allí donde se encuentra la coma de los decimales o el caracter que no sea numérico y no sea el ENTER que terminará la extracción.

En el primer caso, extraería la parte entera del primer número como num1 y fallaría a partir del punto o coma de los decimales, dejando num2 sin extraer. Como lo inicializas a cero, estás haciendo una operación que produce una excepción: num1 % num2.

En el segundo caso, extrae el primer entero, y la parte entera del segundo, y termina fallando al encontrar la coma o el punto decimal. Como resultado tienes num1 relleno y num2 con la parte entera del segundo número. No es que te lo trunque, es que te falla la extracción y ahí se detiene sin extraer más.

Según la documentación, estas cosas producen efectos inesperados.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias! Un saludo.